# How to set custom fields value while inserting new post? Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, custom-fields

I've got a little problem with my code. I want to insert a new post with custom fields values, but these custom fields aren't from WordPress - they're from the theme. Simple solution like: `update_meta_value()` isn't working. I can't even find the theme script that sets values into these fields. 
I found only that much of this code, what concern into my desired field:

```
array(
    'id'        => 'movie_default_fields',
    'type'      => 'select',
    'class'     => 'chosen',
    'title'     => esc_html__('Enable Default Fields', 'amy-movie'),
    'options'   => array(
        'movie_release'     => esc_html__('Release Date', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_duration'    => esc_html__('Duration', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_imdb'        => esc_html__('IMDB', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_mpaa'        => esc_html__('MPAA', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_language'    => esc_html__('Language', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_genre'       => esc_html__('Genre', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_actor'       => esc_html__('Actor', 'amy-movie'),
        'movie_director'    => esc_html__('Director', 'amy-movie'),
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'multiple' => 'multiple',
    ),
    'default'   => array('movie_release', 'movie_duration', 'movie_imdb', 'movie_mpaa', 'movie_language', 'movie_genre', 'movie_actor', 'movie_director')
),
```

```
if (!empty($custom_fields)) {
    foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
        if ($field['type'] == 'text') {
            $name = (isset($field['name']) && $field['name'] != '') ? $field['name'] : '';

            $movie_field[] = array(
                'id'    => sanitize_title($name),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'title' => $name,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

It shows list of custom fields in specific custom post type:

```
if (!function_exists('amy_movie_defaults_fields')) {
    function amy_movie_defaults_fields() {
        $default = array(
            'movie_release',
            'movie_duration',
            'movie_imdb',
            'movie_mpaa',
            'movie_language',
            'movie_genre',
            'movie_actor',
            'movie_director'
        );

        return $default;
    }
}
```

```
if (in_array('movie_duration', $defaults_fields)) {
    $movie_field[] = array(
        'id'    => 'movie_duration',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'title' => esc_html__('Duration', 'amy-movie'),
        'after' => '<em>min</em>',
    );
}
```

I'm trying to work with inserting these values while creating post automatically, but it's not working:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
   'post_type' => 'amy_movie',
   'post_title' => $info->title,
   'post_content' => $desc->description,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'movie_duration' => $info->duration, //simple example
));
```

Comment: Look here at the documentation for wp_insert_post(): 
 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/    'movie_duration' isn't an option there.  You can't just make up fields for that function.  You have to use it the way it's built.

Comment: Unless the theme you're using overloaded that function.  Then I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do to troubleshoot this is put manual entries in to make sure you're using the wp_insert_post() function correctly.  Try this by itself and see if it works.  If it does, then you're just not pulling the values you want from the right places or in the right way:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
   'post_type' => 'amy_movie',
   'post_title' => 'The Big LeBowski',
   'post_content' => 'Movie Duration: 1h 5m',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   //'movie_duration' => $info->duration, //try it without this first.  This function would have to be overloaded by the theme for this to work.
));
```

Comment: Yes, It works normally without these values. I'm getting correct inserts for wordpress like: description and title. Custom fields from theme won't work like this.

Comment: OK, then the custom theme did not overload wp_insert_post().  So, you cannot do that.  Your only field options are the ones in the documentation here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/   You'll have to put all the information about the movie in post_content